# 'auf' oder 'an der' Bushaltestelle?

Tags: grammar, preposition

Welcher Satz ist Richtig?

> Ich bin auf der Bushaltestelle warten

oder

> ich bin an der Bushaltestelle warten?

UND

> der Bus ist auf der Bushaltestelle?

oder

> der Bus ist an der Bushaltestelle

Answer (score 5):

In beiden Fällen ist *an* korrekt

> Ich warte an der Bushaltestelle
>
> Der Bus ist an der Bushaltestelle

Der zweite Satz ist zwar nicht ganz falsch, würde aber als

> Der Bus steht/wartet an der Bushaltestelle

etwas besser klingen .

Comment: Kann ich sagen ich warte auf der Bus? oder ich warte an der Bus? @patrix

Comment: "Ich warte auf den Bus".

Comment: Ein Bus der nicht wartet oder steht, sondern jetzt im Moment diese passiert, ist an der Bushaltestelle. Ansonsten ergänze ich `Der Bus hält an der Bushaltestelle`. Er wartet aber nicht oder zumindest nur selten.

Comment: Seh ich anders. Busse können durchaus warten. > Der Stadtbus wartet an der Haltestelle bis der Fernbus aus Hamburg ankommt.